# Regex to match the first semi colon in a php code

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression that is used to re-define a constant in php file using `preg_match` and input file is screened using htmlspecialchars
eg for

```
define('MEMBERSHIP', 'GOLD');
```

the following regex works

```
/define.*[&quote\']' . $constant . '[&quote;\'].*;/i
```

however it matches the last semi colon, works in most scenarios but fails in a case like the following 
eg:

```
define("MEMBERSHIP", 'GOLD'); // membership subscription; empty means not in use.
```

*notice the last semicolon*, resulting in replaced code as

```
define("MEMBERSHIP", 'SILVER'); empty means not in use.
```

which breaks the code. tried the regex below but it didn't work for those with double quote

```
/define.*[&quote;\']' . $constant . '[&quote;\'][^;]*;/i
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: "but it didn't work"... what exactly happened when you tried the second approach?

Comment: sorry altered the qt, its not working for double quoted lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match corresponding quotes by using a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
'/define[^"\']*(["\'])' . $constant . '\1[^;]*;/i'
```

Otherwise, the negated character class you have at the end is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

if you add a `?` after the `*`, it will become greedy and take the smallest possible amount of characters. So try

```
/define.*?[&quote\']' . $constant . '[&quote;\'].*?;/i
```

to see if it does what you want.

Generally speaking, you should avoid using `.`s if you don't actually mean *any character*.